# gaussian smoothing using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, gaussian

I created the following gaussian kernel in OpenCV and comparing it with the GaussianBlur function of OpenCV. However, I'm getting a black image instead of a smooth image. Can someone throw some light on this?

```
Mat src, dst1,dst2;
Mat gaussiankrnl(3,3,CV_32F);
Point anchor;
double delta;
int ddepth;

anchor = Point( -1, -1 );
delta = 0;
ddepth = -1;

src = imread("coins.pgm");




gaussiankrnl.at<double>(0,0) = 1/16;
gaussiankrnl.at<double>(0,1) = 2/16;
gaussiankrnl.at<double>(0,2) = 1/16;
gaussiankrnl.at<double>(1,0) = 2/16;
gaussiankrnl.at<double>(1,1) = 4/16;
gaussiankrnl.at<double>(1,2) = 2/16;
gaussiankrnl.at<double>(2,0) = 1/16;
gaussiankrnl.at<double>(2,1) = 2/16;
gaussiankrnl.at<double>(2,2) = 1/16;


filter2D(src, dst1, ddepth , gaussiankrnl, anchor, delta, BORDER_DEFAULT );

GaussianBlur(src, dst2, Size(3,3), 1.0);

imshow("result1", dst1 );
imshow("result2", dst2 );

cvWaitKey(0);
return 0;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are dividing integers and making zero kernel.

Change `1/16` to `1.0/16.0` as well as other values.

Comment: hi, thank you. can you tell me why do the results differ? Aren't they supposed to be the same.? I have posted the results here : http://i47.tinypic.com/2qn7br6.png

Comment: changing to 1.0/16.0 helped. In addition i was using CV_32F, which was wrong. Instead, CV_64F has to be used.

Comment: If you write 1/16 in C++ you get integer division which results in 1/16 = 0 that is then cast to double. You have to make at least one of these numbers into double. You could do it by casting or by appending .0 (or only .) at the end of one of the numbers. 1./16 will work as well.